# Inner Product and Linearly Independent

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

*Proposition*. If $u$ and $v$ are nonezero and $\left\langle u,v\right\rangle=0$ then $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent.

Proof. Suppose $\alpha u+\beta v=0$. Then,

**(The statement is my question)** $0=\left\langle \alpha u+\beta v,u\right\rangle=\alpha\left\langle u,u \right\rangle + \beta \left\langle v,v \right \rangle =\alpha \left\| u\right\|
^2$. As $u\neq 0$, $\left\| u\right\|^2\neq 0$. So $\alpha =0$.

Similarly, $\beta =0$.

My questios is the statement, how did we obtain these equivalents?

Comment: Your first line contains an error.  It should be $\beta \langle v,u\rangle$.  which vanishes by assumption.

Comment: @Well, **no similarly**, as $\;\beta=0\;$ doesn't follow from the calculations done to get $\;\alpha=0\;$ , but rather from $\;\alpha u+\beta v=0\;$ ....

Comment: @DonAntonio Then, the proof is enough for $\alpha =0$, isn't it?

Comment: @DonAntonio Can you explain  this '' **the statement** '' clearly?

Comment: @Kahler *After* you already got $\;\beta=0\;$ go back to the first equality in the proof: $$0=\alpha u+\beta v\stackrel{\beta=0}=\alpha u\implies \alpha =0\;\;\text{or}\;\;u=0$$and since it is given $\;u\neq0\;$ we get $\;\alpha=0$ If you ask about the proof itself: it follows at once from the basic properties of inner product...